# Get a list of tables/models in Doctrine 1.2 - Symfony 1.4 and describe?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1, doctrine

How could I fetch all the information about all the models or tables I have in the  database using Doctrine 1.2 in Symfony 1.4.

I need to make a demo about capifony/git/migrations. So I want for an user to perform the following:

- clone the repository
- make a change on the template (any text)
- change schema.yml and generate the migrations-diff
- deploy

So I need to list all the models or tables and each with its columns. In order to demonstrate that the process works

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you need and why?

Comment: @Maerlyn sorry about that - i've edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Doctrine_Connection`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Connection.php) has a function called [`getTables()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Connection.php#L1132), I assume you can get a list of the tables on that connection calling it. According to [this](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Connection.php#L63) it returns an array of [`Doctrine_Table`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Table.php) instances.

That class contains an [array of its column definitions](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Table.php#L70), which you can retrieve by calling [`getColumns()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Table.php#L2152).

I hope that's enough to get you started.